# How can I have custom identifiers/primary keys for my resources?

Tags: graphql, react-admin, dataprovider, hasura

My table has a primary key other than id and react-admin enforces id to be returned in the response by the DataProvider. So can I configure different primary keys/identifiers for my resources?

I am using this library - `https://github.com/Steams/ra-data-hasura-graphql`

Right now I have made few changes in my library code to make this work, but I need an idea to implement it, so anyone using this library doesn't need to go thru whole code to make it work.

```
const config = { 
  'primaryKey': { 
      'tableName': 'primaryKey1', 'tableName2': 'primaryKey2' 
  } 
};
```

I was thinking of something like passing configuration like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is currently possible with the 0.1.0 release. However in hasura you can expose the column with a different name

[hasura column exposed name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01oeb.png)